# Find Specific Pattern in String via SQL

Tags: sql, design-patterns, teradata, matching

I have a column of what we'll call remarks.  Basically notes.
I want to see if I can extract exact patterns of alpha or numbers from these notes see example.

```
 REMARKS                           
 'This is the magic key 24HMBC123456 dont lose it ex644' 
 'Code 31hbxx123456 is tested good px543' 
 'rt445 has tested 61CGRW123456 as good jx163'
```

for the above column I'd test and extract for a pattern of 2 numbers followed by 4 alphas followed by 6 numbers. but I dont know how to code that to get just:

```
    24HMBC123456
    31hbxx123456
    61CGRW123456
```

Any help is appreciated.

I thought to use a case when REGEXP_INSTR mixed with some substrings but this appears either Im over complicating it or its really that complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter your column, you can use

```
SELECT 
   keywords = REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name, '[0-9]{2}[aA-zZ]{4}[0-9]{6}') 
FROM 
   table_name
WHERE 
   NULLIF( REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name, '[0-9]{2}[aA-zZ]{4}[0-9]{6}') , '' ) 
   IS NOT NULL
```

**NOTE**

My SQL is a little 'rusty' - but try for your self.

The Reg-Ex should work according to this [Tester](https://regex101.com/)

**EDIT 1:**

If your search pattern can exists multiple times per row,
this script can help!

```
SELECT 
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name,'[0-9]{2}[aA-zZ]{4}[0-9]{6}',1,LEVEL) 
FROM 
   table_name
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=REGEXP_COUNT(column_name,'[0-9]{2}[aA-zZ]{4}[0-9]{6}')
```

To do some more statistics, you could expand to:

```
SELECT 
   primKey AS RowID,
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name,'[0-9]{2}[aA-zZ]{4}[0-9]{6}',1,LEVEL) AS Pattern
FROM 
   table_name
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=REGEXP_COUNT(column_name,'[0-9]{2}[aA-zZ]{4}[0-9]{6}')
```

**EDIT 2:**

Based on Fred's comment, i replaced the `[aA-zZ]` RegEx-Term.

```
SELECT 
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name,'[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6}',1,LEVEL) 
FROM 
   table_name
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=REGEXP_COUNT(column_name,'[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6}')
```

Comment: This works!  I used REGEXP_SUBSTR(column,'[0-9]{2}[aA-zZ]{4}[0-9]{6}')

Comment: @JamesPizzato Good to hear. Have a good one!

Comment: @JamesPizzato Added and Edit you might find interesting!

Comment: Note that [aA-zZ] or [A-z] will also match the 6 characters between Z and a (the square brackets, backslash, circumflex, underscore, grave accent). You probably want  [A-Za-z] or [[:alpha:]]

Comment: Appreciate it!  Ill be using these frequently.